# Calling a website with results from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small app which calls an URL and scrape the data returned from it. I now want to do something similar for another site but this site uses JavaScript and the results are not included in the html. I've found a way to retrieve the data by using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScript" but to complicate things, the results I want is displayed on the webpage only after I click a button / function on the website:

i.e. To get to display the results I want, I have to:

1) go to the website. (data is displayed but not what I want) 2) click one of the options on the site. (data I really want is displayed)

The URL of this page never changes, as expected being JavaScript. So I want to know if there's a way to call the page so that when the page is displayed, it is already on the option I want, e.g. "https://example.com/page1?option" etc...

I don't know if this is possible since I don't know JavaScript but technically I think it should be?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use the Developer Tools/javascript console on your browser (Chrome has a pretty good one) to see what the browser sends to the server when you click on the button, then use that as the basis for your query.

Comment: Sounds like a job for AJAX. Find what data is being sent when the button is clicked, and then make use of that.

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: Use a headless browser so all the javascript content gets rendered

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @cowbert's suggestion was most helpful and in the console in Chrome it shows an URL which actually gives me exactly the results I want but when I use that URL in my code it says "Method not allowed". How come it worked for the Chrome console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would use the Developer Tools/javascript console on your browser
>   (Chrome has a pretty good one) to see what the browser sends to the
>   server when you click on the button, then use that as the basis for
>   your query. – cowbert

@cowbert's suggestion really did the trick! Upon digging more, I found more results in the Chrome console and one of them actually has the link to the data which is what I need!

Thank you to all who contributed! This is my first post here so if I didn't do something right, please forgive me.